# android studio - R not resolved + Clean project won't work

Tags: android, android-studio

I have this really annoying issue that I have no idea how to fix.

In all my classes I'm presented with the error that "R is not resolved". And I just can't fix it.

Whenever I use "Clean Project" it shows me tons of errors in `app\build\intermediates\manifests\full\debug\AndroidManifest.xml` which most of them look like this:
[image: A part of the file opened. The error presented is the error in most cases.]
I've already tried Cleaning the project, Rebuilding it, and File > Invalidate Caches / Restart... I don't know what to do. I could really use some help.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: And why the -1? My problem is clear, it's not unique just for me, and I presented what I already tried with visual aids. Tell me how it deserves the -1.

Comment: What specific change did you do to your project before the problem started to show up?

Comment: I suspect one of the build steps is failing to actually create the compiled versions of resources. Check to make sure you don't have errors in your resources. It isn't always obvious when something in the res folder fails to build.

Comment: It would probably help to determine if this is a problem with your build/code, or a problem with the configuration of your project in Android Studio. Try a clean and "assemble" using Gradle from the command-line, i.e. "./gradlew clean" followed by "./gradlew assemble". If it compiles ok, then it's a problem with the IDE configuration. If it doesn't compile, then start looking at what code you changed last.

Comment: If this helps: I once had this error, when I added a jpg image to drawable. After removing that the issue was solved.

Answer (score 1):

You can do following steps :

1. Select the File > Project Structure menu option.
2. Press OK on the message box (Project Structure changes don't update build.gradle).
3. Select "Modules" on the "Project Settings" side pane.
4. For each module (project), check that the "Excluded Folders" section does not contain the "build" folder. If they do, press the 'x' button next to the "build" folder.
5. Press OK

Hope this helps.

Comment: I can't seem to find the Excluded Folders section... Could you perhaps add some visual aids? That would be really helpful.

Answer (score 1):

sometimes best way is to just close the project and remove it from recent projects, then re import it. 
legends say it solves many problems!

Answer (score 0):

Just close the project and import it again but remember don't open from **recent project**.

You have two ways to do it, but before the close, the project, go to `File > Close Project.`

1.) In android studio main window click the option `Import project ( Eclipse ADT, Gradle, etc.)`

2.) If the android studio is already running go to `File > New > Import Project...`

Answer (score 0):

Check your Gradle Settings. IF you've changed the gradle version,
change it to 
*classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'*